# What is the difference between collection.find with a callback and without?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is the difference between:

```
var cursor = collection.find();
//do something
```

and

```
collection.find(null, function(err, cursor) {
  //do something
}
```

Does the first one "block?" If so, does "block" mean that it will lock up node until mongo returns the cursor?

(The first example is from the documentation for [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find). If their example is blocking, then why would they put in the documentation?)

Comment: Is this executed in mongodb or in node.js?
If first, then why tag it as node.js ?
if second, what module are you using ?

Comment: This example is using node-mongodb-native. I edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is synchronous, and will block.  If mongo times out, your node server will not be able to do anything else, so essentially "locked up", yes.

This should be avoided unless perhaps during server initialization, or to write command line tools.

The second one will let other events be processed before the callback gets called when the result from mongo is returned.